# Running stable diffusion gives No module named 'ldm.util' error

Tags: python, pip, stable-diffusion

I am trying to run Stable Diffusion with the following command

`python3 scripts/txt2img.py --prompt "red velvet cake" --plms`

I get the following error:

`No module named 'ldm.util'; 'ldm' is not a package`

I tried multiple solutions such as running the command `pip install -e .`
But, it didn't work

Comment: Is this pip in the same environment as python3?

Comment: Yes, everything is in the same virtual environment.

Comment: Do you have a file `ldm.py` around? Rename it so it doesn't shadow `ldm` package.

Comment: There is a file called ldm.py, inside of the ldm package

Comment: https://github.com/CompVis/stable-diffusion/issues?q=is%3Aissue+No+module+named+%27ldm.util%27%3B+%27ldm%27+is+not+a+package

Answer (score 1):

There can be a few potential issues :

1. Avoid Environment Name `ldm`
2. Set Up the Conda Environment

   `conda env create -f environment.yaml` `conda activate ldm`
3. Install Project Dependencies: In your project's root folder, run: `pip install -e .`
4. *if you installed ldm using `pip install ldm` **uninstall it***

Comment: Ok, it seems uninstalling packages that I have installed with ```pip``` and re-installing with ```conda``` causes issues to go away.

Comment: Nope...still an issue

Comment: @ArtF Still same error ?